# Flexbox bug in Internet Explorer <= Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, flexbox

My problem is regarding flexbox layout. Check the demo from modern browsers and Internet Explorer.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.features-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.features-section .custom-col-6 {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  align-self: center;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.features-section .not-for-mobile {
  display: block;
}
.features-section .not-for-desktop {
  display: none;
}
.features-section .feature-image {
  height: 490px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.features-section .feature-image-1 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1430806746135-4c9775bfea07?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f98a2e705cc92fdba353e0d973176aff);
}
.features-section .feature-image-2 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1430806746135-4c9775bfea07?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f98a2e705cc92fdba353e0d973176aff);
}
.features-section .feature-image-3 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1430806746135-4c9775bfea07?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f98a2e705cc92fdba353e0d973176aff);
}
.features-section .feature-image-4 {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1430806746135-4c9775bfea07?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&s=f98a2e705cc92fdba353e0d973176aff);
}
.features-section .feature-item .item-header {
  font-size: 0.857em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 2.8em;
  color: black;
}
.features-section .feature-item .item-text {
  color: #333;
  line-height: 2.1em;
}
.features-section .feature-item i {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.features-section .feature-style-1,
.features-section .feature-style-2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.features-section .feature-style-1 p,
.features-section .feature-style-2 p {
  padding: 0 60px;
}
.features-section .feature-style-3 {
  text-align: left;
}
.features-section .feature-style-3 .icon-wrapper {
  padding: 2px 20px 0 45px;
  float: left;
}
.features-section .feature-style-3 .text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0 35px 0 0;
}
.features-section .feature-style-4 {
  text-align: right;
}
.features-section .feature-style-4 .icon-wrapper {
  padding: 2px 45px 0 20px;
  float: right;
}
.features-section .feature-style-4 .text-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="features-section">
  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-image feature-image-1"></div>
  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-text">
    <div class="feature-item feature-style-1">
      <h4 class="item-header">multipurpose template</h4>
      <p class="item-text">Would you like to pop in a CD and have a better quality of life, and even self improvement? There are three ways you can use music to accomplish this.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-image feature-image-2 not-for-desktop"></div>
  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-text">
    <div class="feature-item feature-style-2">
      <i class="ion-ios-gear-outline"></i>
      <h4 class="item-header">multipurpose template</h4>
      <p class="item-text">Would you like to pop in a CD and have a better quality of life, and even self improvement? There are three ways you can use music to accomplish this.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-image feature-image-2 not-for-mobile"></div>

  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-image feature-image-3"></div>
  <div class="custom-col-6 feature-text">
    <div class="feature-item feature-style-3">
      <div class="icon-wrapper"><i class="ion-ios-gear-outline"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h4 class="item-header">multipurpose template</h4>
        <p class="item-text">Would you like to pop in a CD and have a better quality of life, and even self improvement? There are three ways you can use music to accomplish this.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Zharkov/pen/LbENQm)

---

So, in IE all flex items are in one row, but I need every item to occupy half of the row.

Comment: Please specify which Internet Explorer version you are using.

Comment: I use the last one version - Edge

Comment: I don't see any bug or difference between browsers in your demo.

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz https://pp.vk.me/c604418/v604418181/3f7bb/TnMqnfqFBm8.jpg https://pp.vk.me/c604418/v604418181/3f7c5/qSgW9aE9AWY.jpg

Comment: Did u use ms vendor prefixes?

Comment: @AdamWolski Yes, sure.